# first text game...cant figure out code for potion

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble with 1 line of code I've run it over and over again but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm thinking it's the `if` statement but I'm not sure. The line I'm having trouble with is in the comment. I don't know how to write it so it works properly.

```
import random

print"Hello hero, you are surrounded by a horde of orcs"
print"that span as far as the eye can see"
print"you have 5 health potions, 200 health"
print"you can either fight, run, or potion"

h=200 #health
w=0 #wave
o=0 #orc
p=5 #potion

while h>=0:
    print"you run into a horde of orcs what will you do?"
    a=raw_input("fight, run, potion")
    if a=="fight":
        print"you draw your sword and begin to fight"
        d=random.randint(1, 20)
        w+=1
        o+=1
        p=5
        h-=d
        print"you survive this horde"
        print("you have, "+str(h)+" health left")
    elif a=="potion":
        print"you have used a potion"
        h+=20
        p=p-1
        print"you have recovered 20 health"
        print("you now have, "+str(h)+" health")
        if p==0: #supposed to be if potion = 0 print (you dont have any left)
            print"you dont have any left"
    elif a=="run":
        h-=5
        print"you got away but suffered 5 damage"
        print("you have, "+str(h)+" health left")
print"you  have fought well but alas hero you were defeated"
print("you survived, "+str(w)+" waves and have killed, "+str(o)+" orcs")
```

Comment: This probably won't fix anything, but I have a suggestion. Use variable names that are longer than one letter. Then instead of writing `if p==0: #supposed to be if potion = 0`, you can just write `if potion == 0:` without the comment. It will save you typing in the long run :-)

Comment: And how is it not working? Does it never print? Is it allowing you to use negative potions?

Comment: ya I probably should start using full names, just a habit that I have, @thegrinner-the program would still run but like you said it would still let me use negative potions

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to test if you have any potions before you award the benefits of using one.  Like this:

```
elif a=="potion":
    if p==0: #supposed to be if potion = 0 print (you dont have any left)
        print"you dont have any left"    
    else:
        print "you have used a potion"
        h+=20
        p=p-1
        print "you have recovered 20 health"
        print "you now have, "+str(h)+" health"
```

Also you have a lot of little things related to how you are using print that you should sort out, here is a cleaned up version of your original Python script (which I tested, and it appears to work, good luck with your game :)

```
import random

print "Hello hero, you are surrounded by a horde of orcs"
print "that span as far as the eye can see"
print "you have 5 health potions, 200 health"
print "you can either fight, run, or potion"

h=200 #health
w=0 #wave
o=0 #orc
p=5 #potion

while h>=0:
    print "you run into a horde of orcs what will you do?"
    a=raw_input("fight, run, potion")
    if a=="fight":
        print "you draw your sword and begin to fight"
        d=random.randint(1, 20)
        w+=1
        o+=1
        p=5
        h-=d
        print "you survive this horde"
        print "you have, "+str(h)+" health left"
    elif a=="potion":
        if p==0: #supposed to be if potion = 0 print (you dont have any left)
            print "you dont have any left"
        else:
            print "you have used a potion"
            h+=20
            p=p-1
            print "you have recovered 20 health"
            print "you now have, "+str(h)+" health"
    elif a=="run":
        h-=5
        print "you got away but suffered 5 damage"
        print "you have, "+str(h)+" health left"

print "you  have fought well but alas hero you were defeated"
print "you survived, "+str(w)+" waves and have killed, "+str(o)+" orcs"
```

Comment: ....wow I cant believe I didnt catch that. thank you, I was trying to figure it out for about 1 hour now and it was such an easy fix

Comment: Im learning from a book and in the book they are using python 3.0 I think, and they use the () around text so I started using () when I needed to concatenate strings together. but now I know that I dont need to use them thank you again

Answer (score 0):

here's what you should add to your code:

```
elif a=="potion":
    if p>0:
        print"you have used a potion"
        h+=20
        p=p-1
        print"you have recovered 20 health"
        print("you now have, "+str(h)+" health")
    else: #supposed to be if potion = 0 print (you dont have any left)
        print"you dont have any potion left"
        continue
```